# Make Notification Area icons stay in Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-vista, notification-area

I am wondering how it is possible to make the Notification Area icons stay in the Windows 7 taskbar even when you click on the arrow next to them like they did in Windows Vista and XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on the arrow and select "Customize" you will be able to set the display settings for each icon type.
Optoins are:

- Show icon and notifications
- Hide icon and notifications
- Only show notifications

In this context, "Hidden" refers to when the icon is only found after clicking on the arrow and doesnt remain on the taskbar by default.

Hope this helps!